# How to stop gracefully a Pulumi up command

Tags: python, devops, minikube, pulumi, helm3

I am trying to develop a couple of Helm Charts on Minikube. 
To do that I am running *pulumi up* on a Minikube environment.

```py
import pulumi
from pulumi_kubernetes.helm.v3 import Chart, ChartOpts, FetchOpts, RepositoryOptsArgs
import pulumi_kubernetes as k8s

config = pulumi.Config()
is_minikube = config.require_bool("isMinikube")

datahub_prerequisites = Chart(
    "prerequisites",
    ChartOpts(
        chart="datahub-prerequisites",
        fetch_opts=FetchOpts(
            repo="https://helm.datahubproject.io/",
        ),
        values = {
            'elasticsearch': {
                'replicas': 1,
                'minimumMasterNodes': 1,
                'clusterHealthCheckParams': 'wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s',
                'antiAffinity': "soft"
            }, 
            'neo4j-community': {
                'enabled': 'true' 
            }   
        } 
    )
)

datahub_prerequisites = Chart(
    "datahub",
    ChartOpts(
        chart="datahub",
        fetch_opts=FetchOpts(
            repo="https://helm.datahubproject.io/",
        ),
    ),
)
```

I made a mistake since I should have used the *depends on* property so that the datahaub helmchart is developed after the prerequisites. 
Now some of the resources failed to create and **pulumi up is not terminating**. 
It is not a problem of minikube resources: I checked with minikube top.
I tried to launch the *pulumi destroy* in another terminal window but this error occurs:

```
error: the stack is currently locked by 1 lock(s). Either wait for the other process(es) to end or manually delete the lock file(s).
```

I am quite a beginner and I would like to understand the best practices in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a Pulumi program, Pulumi creates a lock file to ensure nobody else can attempt to run operations on that Pulumi program.

You can cancel a `pulumi up` operation in the same way as more other Go programs or other Unix like tools, by sending a `SIGINT` via `ctrl+c`.

The first `SIGINT` will attempt to *gracefully* stop the Pulumi program execution, a second `SIGINT` will attempt to forcefully stop the program execution.

The final mechanism to stop a Pulumi program in this situation is to completely terminate Pulumi with a `SIGKILL`. This may or may not leave a lock file in place, which you can clean up using `pulumi cancel`.

However, there is something to consider in this situation.

If you cancel a running pulumi program, Pulumi will no longer be able to confirm the state of the operation in your cloud provider API (in this case Kubernetes) and reconcile that status with your Pulumi state. You'll need to run `pulumi refresh` so that Pulumi can reconcile your cloud provider resources with the pulumi state. It's usually safe to run a `pulumi destroy` in this scenario, as Pulumi will simply destroy all resources it knows about

Comment: Problem for me is I was using s3 as a backend and my lockfile was stored there, normally SIGINT would destroy the lock but if you have the backend set you need to destroy it from s3

Comment: @Cr4zyTun4 You can get `pulumi cancel` to delete the lockfile from S3 bucket.  This works for me: `PULUMI_BACKEND_URL='s3://my-pulumi-bucket/?region=us-west-1&awssdk=v2&profile=my-aws-profile' pulumi cancel my-stack` - same URL as used in Pulumi's [S3 backend docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/state/#aws-s3)

Answer (score 1):

1. Received error - the stack is currently locked by 1 lock(s). Either wait for the other process(es) to end or manually delete the lock file(s).
2. Go to the respective location where the lock file is stored in the backend and delete the lock file
3. pulumi refresh and go from there

i.e pulumi refresh only worked after clearing the lock file

Answer (score 0):

In the recent version, we could use pulumi cancel

pulumi up
error: the stack is currently locked by 1 lock(s). Either wait for the other process(es) to end or delete the lock file with `pulumi cancel`.

pulumi cancel
This will irreversibly cancel the currently running update for 'stack-name'!
Please confirm that this is what you'd like to do by typing `stack-name`: stack-name
The currently running update for 'stack-name' has been canceled!